# Making an OR query more streamlined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do a search by customerType, and I'm running into a small problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip FROM qrySearchFields 
WHERE  CustomerID in (Select CustomerID from tblCustomerTypeLineItems Where CustomerTypeID = 241)
```

takes less than a second to run, and so does:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip FROM qrySearchFields 
WHERE CustomerID in (Select CustomerID from tblCustomerTypeLineItems Where CustomerTypeID = 240)
```

But when I try to use an OR to look for both types at once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip FROM qrySearchFields WHERE
CustomerID in (Select CustomerID from tblCustomerTypeLineItems Where CustomerTypeID = 241) 
Or CustomerID in (Select CustomerID from tblCustomerTypeLineItems Where CustomerTypeID = 240)
```

it takes about 40 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this, or something that I'm missing?
For more background, see the parent question: [Displaying Query Results Horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960947/displaying-query-results-horizontally)

Comment: Is `DISTINCT` used on purpose here?

Comment: Yes. The front end is a program that we use to keep track of customers. the user has a combo box that they can query against, and CustomerType is one of them. So they select CustomerType in the first combo box, select the type they want in the second (which supplies the ID) and a logical operator (AND, OR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not restructure your `OR` query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip 
  FROM qrySearchFields 
 WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                        FROM tblCustomerTypeLineItems 
                       WHERE CustomerTypeID IN (241, 240))
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and above, you could use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
WITH cteCustomerId AS 
(
    SELECT CustomerID
      FROM tblCustomerTypeLineItems
     WHERE CustomerTypeID IN (241, 240)
)
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip
  FROM qrySearchFields
 WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID
                        FROM cteCustomerId);
```

Comment: I like this, but it's going to take some thought.

Comment: The front end is a program that builds the query for the user, so for instance they select a field to query against, and a value to query for. they might pick one CustomerType, or eight, and the program has to figure it out how to write the query so that it returns the right results... The last guy had it running against a CSV CustomerTypes (,130,16,197,), which was a big pain to maintain each time a customer type was added or removed. As CustomerType is one of 30 fields, getting it programed to handle this solution will be tricky.

Comment: @AndyD273: That will rule out the `CTE` then.

Comment: Yeah. I'm gonna have to think about this for a while. My only other idea is to use COALESCE in a user function to make the customer types into a CSV value (,241,16,197,), which works except I can't query against it. SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip, dbo.getCustomerTypes(CustomerID) as CustomerTypeIds FROM qrySearchFields WHERE CustomerTypeIds = '%,241,%' returns Invalid column name 'CustomerTypeIds'.

Comment: It should be `WHERE CustomerTypeIds LIKE '%,241,%'` and not equals.

Comment: Like has the same effect (Invalid column name 'CustomerTypeIds'). I think it probably doesn't like that the column is the return of a function. I'll keep looking into it. also trying to figure out how to make it work with SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomerTypeLineItems WHERE CustomerTypeID IN (241, 240))

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look into it. the good news is that the way I've been doing it doesn't take any longer as you add more OR's past the origional 2. So I temporarally upped the timeout until I can figure out how to make this work in the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why using `OR` in the outer query?

Try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip
FROM    qrySearchFields
WHERE   CustomerID IN
        (
        SELECT  CustomerID
        FROM    tblCustomerTypeLineItems
        WHERE   CustomerTypeID IN (240, 241)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's having to do a lot more work because of the two SELECT IN statements; much more efficient to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, CustomerName, City, State, Zip 
FROM qrySearchFields
WHERE CustomerID in
      (Select CustomerID from tblCustomerTypeLineItems Where CustomerTypeID IN (240,241))
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2 subqueries are probably fairly expensive. Give this version a try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sf.CustomerID, sf.CustomerName, sf.City, sf.State, sf.Zip 
    FROM qrySearchFields sf
        INNER JOIN tblCustomerTypeLineItems ctli
            ON sf.CustomerID = ctli.CustomerID
                AND ctli.CustomerTypeID IN (240,241)
```